# Mixare - How to in built into Android app

Tags: android

I was wondering, for integrating MIXARE into my Android app. I came across the post

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

but i got a question that is, do my phone or tablet need to be installed with MIXARE ? or i will be just launching the functions of mixare in my app ?

Apologies if you guys don't quite understand my question.

Nevertheless i still hope to have some answers.

Thanks.

Comment: What is Mixare exactly? Are you referring to the Zxing library?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions given do NOT require that other software be installed on the device - the library referred to is an android library which is installed on your development machine are including in your application as part of the distribution (i.e in the APK).

If you choose this route be sure to test on some devices which DO have the other app installed because if you get the intent filters even slightly wrong it will fail in this case.

However this is NOT the best solution: there are several different reasons why it is better to install the Mixare application and use the intent system to access it from your code, possibly the best of these is that it allows the user to keep the latest version of the external app updated. The author of your link clearly indicates that the only reason he chose this path was because within his enterprise solution no access to the play store was permitted.